# Linea de comando xcopy que realiza búsqueda de varios archivos y los copie en otro destino

Tags: windows, cmd, línea-de-comandos

Quisiera saber si hay la posibilidad de hacer en una linea de comando en windows prompt (CMD) que permita búsqueda de ciertos archivos, los copie y los guarde en otra dirección.

hasta ahora solo sé hacer el xcopy para 1 solo archivo:

```
XCOPY \\direccion del server\carpeta origen\file.ext D:\Backup
```

pero tengo mas de 300,000 archivos en la carpeta origen y solo necesito menos de 500 archivos para hacerle respaldo.

hay algún método similar?

Comment: Es necesario que indiques si los ficheros a copiar están en un mismo directorio y si tienen algún patrón, por ejemplo la misma extensión, o alguna letras comunes en el nombre.

Comment: Pues todos los ficheros están en el mismo directorio.

Comment: Sobre el fichero en si... Todos tienen el formato: auto numérico.ext y deseo que el xcopy ponga los ficheros que deseo y los copié en disco de respaldo... El problema es que no sé cómo hacerlo por qué solo puedo hacer una línea de xcopy y en esa línea espesifico solo un fichero y es tedioso hacer la búsqueda en el buscador de Windows con un OR y que busque los 500 ficheros

Comment: Como hablas de respaldo, tengo la sensación de que solo te interesan copiar lo más recientes. Si es así, puede utilizar la opción /D de xcopy, que copia los modificados a partir de la fecha incluida. Por ejemplo, para copiar los ficheros modificados o creados después del día 1 de Octubre de 2018 (1 de octubre incluido : XCOPY \\direccion del server\carpeta origen\*.ext /D:01-10-2018 D:\Backup

Comment: La sugerencia es buena cuando son en periodo de tiempo recientes ... Pero igual en la búsqueda del fichero corresponde a búsqueda de 30 días  y son ciertos archivos... Por ejemplo nesesito copiar el archivo 1,2,4,7,18 por ejemplo

Comment: Una posible solución es hacer un fichero .bat con un for dentro que recorra todos los ficheros del directorio. Pero necesito unos ejemplos más concretos: nombres de ficheros que sí entran y nombres de ficheros que no entran. Si no se consigue un patrón para distinguir unos de otros, no veo solución

Comment: estaba tratando de hacer el for antes de formular la pregunta pero desconozco la forma de implementarlo en linea de comando.  los ficheros tienen este nombre que es un auto-numérico: _17012295.vox,17012296.vox,17012297.vox, 17012298.vox, 17012299.vox,17012300.vox_   y digamos que en el rango de lunes a viernes solo fueron seleccionadas: 17012296.vox, 17012297.vox y 17012300.vox. el detalle es que en el rango de lunes a viernes, la cantidad que hay que hacerle back-up es de 400 files aproximado en un directorio con 295,769 files

Comment: No lo entiendo muy bien. Por un lado parece que son 400 los ficheros de los que hay hacer backup pero justo antes has enumerado solo 3. La pregunta sigue siendo la misma: cómo (una manera que se pueda plasmar de manera legible para el ordenador) se sabe qué ficheros deben ser respaldados, y cuáles no?

Comment: Claro. De un BD se extrae un reporte en .csv y en ese reporte se mencionan cuantos files son los que se van a seleccionar en la semana. Obviamente no puedo ejemplificarlo ya que la magnitud del ejemplo no cabría en este medio. Los 300,000 files son grabaciones de 30 dias y solo se requiere guardar las que fueron evaluadas. Y solo son por semana aproximadamente 400.